# How do I make a dynamic selectable list that's NOT a dropdown

Tags: html, angular

Here is my current code:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="items">
    <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item " {{item .symbol}} : {{item.companyName}}</option>
</select>
```

The problem is this is a dropdown that is not fully expanded by default.  My goal is to have this list act similar to how Google has their search; A fully expanded list that updates based on the input.

I have the binding correct, but I can't seem to get the HTML correct to where it's always expanded and there is no empty entry for the first element.

Are the Select/Option tags the incorrect tags to use?

I can't find any other tags to use.  Anything in Angular?

Comment: `<select multiple [(ngModel)]="items">`...?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if natively you can have this feature inside a browser. But you can write one component to do this job. Basically, it'll have two parts, one input, and one panel with some help via Bootstrap.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-xs">
<ul class="dropdown-menu"></ul>
```

When you type in anything in the input, you can make the list of items displayed. After you select one item, the list can disappear. In terms of style, it'll be very similar to http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#dropdowns

Then you can wrap up everything inside an angular component. I know it's a long answer.